# Is there any way to dynamically update the option list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the below form:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec

The listed options in the second input "JOINT" are generated from this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_LSdBkvw5Z6L4ZQP5qZccLEfekNVRCeKQRLLb9Vm4eM/edit#gid=285745421

The form submits are shown here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_LSdBkvw5Z6L4ZQP5qZccLEfekNVRCeKQRLLb9Vm4eM/edit#gid=0

As you can see, the form reads the options correctly (W 01, W 02, ..) but when submitting the form, the sheet reads the submitted options as Option 01, Option 02 and so on

The question is, is there any way to make the sheet reads the options as indicated in the form (W 01, W 02, ..) and also is there any way to update the list in the form dynamically instead of setting a number of options (from Option 01 to Option 08) as indicated in the html code

Thanks in advance

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index.html')
    .evaluate() // evaluate MUST come before setting the Sandbox mode
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
lock.tryLock(10000)

try {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues() 
[0]
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow 
}))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

catch (e) {
return ContentService
  .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}

finally {
lock.releaseLock()
}
}


function createInnerHTML(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var names = ss.getSheetByName("CHOICES");
var namesValues = names.getRange(2, 2, names.getMaxRows() - 
1).getValues(); 
return namesValues;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
</style>

<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">

<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

<div class="ss-q-title">JOINT
<span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span></div>

<? var namesValues= createInnerHTML(); ?>  
<div><select name="JOINT" id="JOINT" aria-label="JOINT" required>
<option value=""></option>
<option value="OPTION 01"><?= namesValues[0][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 02"><?= namesValues[1][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 03"><?= namesValues[2][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 04"><?= namesValues[3][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 05"><?= namesValues[4][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 06"><?= namesValues[5][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 07"><?= namesValues[6][0]?></option>
<option value="OPTION 08"><?= namesValues[7][0]?></option>
</select></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" class="jfk- 
button jfk-button-action "></form>

<script>
const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwTGqZqLTAsOpSweMn0xgHP0sOJPsFg5ZShC1HqzVoDoNi5h5Y/exec'
const form = document.forms['submit-to-google-sheet']
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
  .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
 })
</script>

<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/formdata-polyfill"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/promise-polyfill@latest"></script>
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/whatwg-fetch@latest"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- Providing `value` attribute to each `option` causes the value provided to be submitted to the server instead of the text content of the option

#### Solution:

- Omit the `value` attribute of `option` element.

#### Snippet:

```
<option><?= namesValues[0][0]?></option>
```

#### Reference:

- [Html Element#option § Atrributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#Attributes)

  > value
  > The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.